# Butter spatters more than others

Tags: butter

I usually use one kind of unsalted butter from the grocery store but my wife bought another brand for no known reason. I heated a tablespoon in a pan today and noticed it spattered far more than my usual brand which, to me, indicates more water content in the butter. Agreed? [(EDIT: Yes it's true.)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75282/1672)

Which leads to my question, what does that say about the quality of the butter if anything?

Both companies are well known brands with good reputations.

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75282/1672 (doesn't seriously discuss comparison between brands though, I don't think)

Comment: @Jefromi I searched for "spatter" so I guess that's why I didn't see that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it seems you answered your own question, though you then expand this question of fat content to "quality."

"Quality" of butter is subjective.  It depends a lot on application.  Higher fat does *not* necessarily mean better flavor or better performance (particularly as an ingredients in things like baking).  See, for example, [this article](http://www.sfgate.com/recipes/article/When-Put-to-the-Test-Here-s-How-Butter-Brands-3236719.php), which discusses the ranking of butter in a number of applications.  Fat content varied from 80% to about 86%, but that wasn't highly correlated with superior results.  The tasters' opinions there came down in favor of the lower-fat butter for applications like pound cake (where they claimed more steam from the higher-moisture content added to lift) and buerre blanc (where they claimed the excess fat unbalanced the flavors of the sauce).

But I think this is probably more evidence that American recipes are likely calibrated to assume butters on the lower edge of spectrum, around the legal minimum of 80% butterfat content.

Anyhow, my personal experience is that processing matters a lot more than butterfat content.  In particular, I generally taste a strong difference between cultured vs. "sweet cream" butters.  And salt content can make a huge difference.  But another thing that came up is storage/wrapping, as fat tends to absorb odors and other flavors, as mentioned in the above article and in a [Cook's Illustrated review article](http://www.vermontcreamery.com/stuff/contentmgr/files/0/a682d402de5561bfb7f4bde235dc65c5/files/ci_article.pdf) that also ranked butters in various applications.  I find it interesting that this article is available on the Vermont Creamery website, which makes a [big point](http://www.vermontcreamery.com/what-is-cultured-butter) of how it has the "highest butterfat content you can obtain when making butter" of 86%; even they are posting an article whose title is basically that butterfat may not matter as much as other factors.

(By the way, I'd personally disagree with the CI characterization of cultured butters in general as having "artificial, margarine-like" flavors.  But everyone has their own preferences, and I think American palates have shifted to expect "sweet cream" butter.)

Comment: I, for one, love the taste of cultured butter and find regular butter bland. But I've never used cultured butter in baking. Have you and if so, are some recipes better or worse using it?

Comment: @Jude - given the price of good cultured butter, I mostly have used it as a spread.  I have occasionally tried it out in baking, and the only place I noticed a difference was in croissants.  But I don't know whether it was the "cultured" aspect of the butter, the higher butterfat content, or some other aspect that actually made them stand out. I once made a pound cake with expensive cultured butter, and frankly didn't notice much of a difference. I'd read the linked articles above, since they clearly did a lot more experimentation here than I have with baking.

Comment: Is 6% (1/2 a tablespoon in a whole stick of butter) really noticeable?

Comment: @RonJohn - As I noted in the answer above, it likely depends on the application.  The highest moisture content in my first link was 17.78% (for a butter that was 81% fat), while the lowest moisture content was 12.59% (for a butter that was 86% fat).  That may be seem like a small difference in fat, but it's actually a 40+% increase in moisture content (17.78/12.59 = 1.41).  Yes, that can make a difference in splattering or in applications where you depend on moisture in butter to evaporate for lift, etc.

Answer (score 1):

More splattering means higher water content. Higher water content means reduced fat which means reduced flavor.

[NY Times article:](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/10/30/garden/i-ll-have-my-milk-with-cream-and-pass-the-butter.html)

> Chefs like the butter for its low water content and rich flavor.
>   Instead of being 80 percent fat, the minimum required by the
>   Government since 1923, Plugra is 82 percent fat.

[Related Washington Post article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/articles/A18675-2004Nov2.html)

My spattering butter was Oberweiss. My regular butter for frying is Land O'Lakes.

Comment: You should be able to judge this from the nutrition facts, although if it's a small difference 80 vs 82% it might be smaller than the rounding for the serving size. I'd also be pretty surprised if that scale of difference were that noticeable in spattering: for, say, 4 tablespoons of butter that's the difference between 11g and 12g of water.

Comment: In Germany we can buy a thing called Butterschmalz, which has been treated to remove all but the fat.They usually claim around 99% butter fat, and it's great for cooking with.

Comment: @RedSonja in English *clarified butter* -- not far from a direct translation of *geläuterte Butter* (alternative name according to wikipedia) if my German doesn't let me down.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the water content of the butter is responsible for the excessive spattering, bubbling and spitting of hot butter. Store brand at Walmart is very good; Ralphs Kroger brand is awful! I do a LOT of butter frying in my cast iron skillets: pre-boiled potatoes, onions, eggs, Great Northern Beans, even sauerkraut, so good frying butter is important.

Comment: Unfortunately, store brands like that will be sourced from various dairies depending on region, so your experience based on a particular store won’t generalise to others.